# How can I check if AVMetadataItem items like Title, Artist, etc , are null or don't exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avmetadataitem

I am building a music app and I am trying to get the MP3 files metadata with this piece of code:

```
for (NSString *format in [assest availableMetadataFormats]) {

        for (AVMetadataItem *item in [assest metadataForFormat:format]) {
            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"title"]) {

                [SongNameMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item value]]];
            }
            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artist"]) {

                [ArtistMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item value]]];
            }
            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"albumName"]) {

            }
            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {
                UIImage *img = nil;
                if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
                    img = [UIImage imageWithData:item.dataValue];

                }
                else {
                    NSDictionary *dict ;
                    [item.value copyWithZone:nil];
                    img = [UIImage imageWithData:[dict objectForKey:@"data"]];

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code works fine. Only thing is that when the mutable arrays are filled, they do it in the following way:

- SongNameMutableArray => [song1, song2, song3, songX];
- ArtistMutableArray   => [Artists1, Artist3, Artist 10, ArtistX];

Because not all songs have an artist in the metadata.

According to this specific part of the code

```
if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artist"]) {
    [ArtistMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item value]]];
}
```

If the item found is the artist, insert it in the array.

Now my question is how to detect when a song has no artist in the metadata? So that i can insert "null" in ArtistMutableArray   => [Artists1, null, Artist3, null, Artist 5, ArtistX];

**I tried with:**

```
if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"null"])
if ([[item value] isEqualToString:@"null"])
```

I am not sure what I am missing in here.

Comment: Have you tried comparing to nil? [item value] == nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you are doing needs to be done differently. Don't split the data into separate arrays, especially if you want each array to have the same number of elements and each corresponding index refers to the same asset.

Instead, define a class that contains the few properties you want to track for each asset. Then have a single array of those class instances. Then there is no need to worry about keeping multiple arrays in sync and perform tricks by adding "null" values to an array where needed.

There are many other benefits to having one array of data. For example, sorting. By having one array, you can sort that one array of data by artist, for example. Trying to keep multiple arrays in sync when sorting or filtering is a huge pain.

Since you are getting just the common metadata there is no need to iterate over all formats and look at the properties of each format. Just use the `commonMetadata` property of the asset.

When getting the `commonKey` value, do not compare it against hardcoded strings. Use the constants provided by the API such as `AVMetadataCommonKeyAlbumName`.

And since each metadata item can only have one value for `commonKey`, use `if/else` to make your code more efficient. And use the `stringValue` property of the metadata item to get a string value instead of using `stringWithFormat`.

Here is a start for your metadata class. Name as you see fit and add whatever other properties you need.

```
@interface MyMetaData: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *artist;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *albumName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *artwork;

@end

@implementation MyMetaData
@end
```

And here's a replacement for the code you posted in your question:

```
NSMutableArray *metadata = [NSMutableArray array]; // your array of obtained metadata

AVAsset *asset = // some asset

MyMetaData *data = [[MyMetaData alloc] init];

NSArray *commonData = asset.commonMetadata;
for (AVMetadataItem *item in commonData) {
    AVMetadataKey key = item.commonKey;
    if ([key isEqual: AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle]) {
        data.title = item.stringValue;
    } else if ([key isEqual:AVMetadataCommonKeyArtist]) {
        data.artist = item.stringValue;
    } else if ([key isEqual:AVMetadataCommonKeyAlbumName]) {
        data.albumName = item.stringValue;
    } else if ([key isEqual:AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork]) {
        data.artwork = // your code to get the image
    }
}

[metadata addObject:data];
```

This is much cleaner and you now only have one array to deal with. If a given asset doesn't have data for, say the artist, that value simply remain `nil` on the given `MyMetaData` instance.

Comment: Thank you :) . I think it works fine . My only concern now is the fact that i would need to print every title, artist, etc, in a `UITableViewController`.

I have tried something like : `cell.TitleLabel.text = data.title` 
but it won't work because of the IndexPath.row. Do you have any suggestions once more ? :)

Comment: It would be more like `cell.titleLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].title`.

Comment: When i type  `metadata[indexPath.row].title;` ( assuming that metadata is the NSMutableArray, then i get this => `Property 'title' not found on object of type 'id'`. Weird :(

Comment: Then split the line. `MyMetaData *data = metadata[indexPath.row];`. `cell.titleLabel.text = data.title;`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are a genius :)

Comment: I just got 1 more question : How can I check if a title or artist is null? Because in the For it seems to only add to the array those elements that are not null ( which is normal ). How can I detect the null items in advance ? :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by detecting in advance. A given `MyMetaData` may have `nil` values for `artist` or `title` which you can check for when populating your table view cell or any other time you access a specific `MyMetaData` object from your array.

Comment: Exactly. The point is to detect those nil values from `MyMetaData `. Lets say because a song may have a nil value in album. The question is how to get those nil values. The point of everything is to show a "no album found" message in the tableview :)

Comment: `text = data.title ? data.title : @"no title";`. That's the rough line of code.

Comment: `if ([key isEqual: AVMetadataCommonKeyAlbumName]) {
                data.albumName = item.stringValue;`

That'd be the "normal" piece of code.

Now to get when the album is null, when there's no album , that is. Then the code would be like : `if ([something]) {
                data.albumName = @"no album";`

What's that something ? :)

Comment: No. Do not set `albumName` to some arbitrary text when building up your array. Only when you wish to display the album name, detect if the value is nil or not. If it's nil, then show some alternate default value, otherwise show the actual name. This is far more flexible.

Comment: Exactly, what is what i am asking :) . **detect if the value is nil or not. If it's nil, then show some alternate default value** <-- what's the piece of code for that ? :)

Comment: And that's what I stated several comments again. `text = data.albumName ? data.albumName : @"no album";

Comment: Ouch, I got it now :) . I just needed to do this : if([metadata[indexPath.row]artist] == nil) cell.ArtistLabel.text = @"No artist defined"; else cell.ArtistLabel.text = [metadata[indexPath.row]artist]; . One last question : How do i actually sort the array by lets say "Title" ? :)

Comment: Can you help me please ? :)

Comment: I've already answered the question you posted above. Sorting an array of custom struct is a completely different question. Do some searching, it has been discussed before. If you need help after that, post a new question specific to your new issue.